Forge viewer cache issue on NEXTJS
I have built an app with APS viewer (using NextJS 14), and I can't get this to work. When I upload a new model to the same bucket with the same name, even using 'x-ads-forcé': 'true', and HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, Will still show the old model.
This is my translationJob function:
export const createTranslationJob = async (urn: string) => {
    const responseToken = await getToken();
    const token = responseToken.data.access_token;
    const postURL = `${credentials.BaseURL}/modelderivative/${credentials.Version}/designdata/job`;

    const postBody = {
        input: {
            urn
        },
        output: {
            formats: [
                {
                    type: "svf2",
                    views: ["2d", "3d"]
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    const response = await axios.post(postURL, postBody, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            // 'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'x-ads-force': 'true', //force to delete the existing manifest and create a fresh manifest
            //CORS
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}`,
        }
    });

    return response;
}

And this is my init viewer function:
export const initViewer = async (divId: string) => {
    let viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D;

    const getClientToken = await Client.getAccesstoken();
    // debugger;
    const tolkenData = getClientToken.data;
    const tolken = tolkenData.access_token;
    const options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
        api: 'streamingV2',
        accessToken: tolken,
    };

    await Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
        const config3d = {
            extensions: [
                // 'CameraLockExtension',
                // 'EventsTutorial',
                // 'CustomizedToolbarExtension'
                // 'rebarColorExtension',
            ],
        };
        Autodesk.Viewing.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
            "If-Modified-Since": "Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT"
        };
        const htmlDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv!, config3d);
        const startedCode = viewer.start();
        if (startedCode > 0) {
            console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        }
        console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');


    });
    return viewer!;
}

Any Help on this problem??
I tried with solution on this post:
Forge viewer cache issue
Without luck
